# Background color being canceled by "float"

Tags: html, css

Explanation of code:

I'm creating a bar with three links. I made the bar, and tried to space out the links using the `float`, `text-align`, and `width`. (I'm trying to get the center link centered and the other two equidistant from it, and equidistant from the sides.) However, when I originally did it with 3 `divs` (the `divs` other than the "I" `divs`), the background color disappeared. So I messed with it and realized the float on the third link's `div` was causing the problem. So I added another `div`(the final `div`), and that worked with a little text. However, since I had to put text in it, it threw off my spacing. So I made a `div` on the other side(the first one) to balance it out. It still throws off my spacing without float however!

Question(s):

Why does having the `float`property on the final `div` in a line cause the background color to disappear?

```
<div style="padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:#3C3C3C;">
    <div style="color:#3C3C3C;float:left;">
        I
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:50px;width:20%;float:left;text-align:center;">
        <a style="color:#3690B7;" href="">
            Hello
        </a>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;text-align:center;">
        <a style="color:#3690B7;" href="">
            Hello
        </a>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-right:50px;width:20%;float:left;text-align:center;">
        <a style="color:#3690B7;" href="">
            Hello
        </a>
    </div>
    <div style="color:#3C3C3C;float:right;">
        I
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: mind creating a fiddle?

Comment: oops, forgot I can't delete my own question... derp. Flagged.

Comment: See answer from @Sefiroz, then read this: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 3):

You have to clear floating by adding for example another div below your final div:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: i find this cleaner than overflow:auto, since it encourages the practice of clearing floats as one is supposed to. btw he means your last "inner" div

Comment: yes, after final INNER div ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: auto` to your outer `<div>`:

```
<div style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#3C3C3C; overflow: auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that because you are floating elements within another element that isn't floated causes the wrapping element to be rendered as if it is empty.

To fix this, you can add some widths and a `float:left;` on the wrapping `div`

Check out this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifeWuvO/1/edit) example which seems to be what you are looking for.

Basically your first `div` should be like;

```
<div style="padding:0px; margin:0px; background-color:#3C3C3C;float: left; width: 100%;">
```

Then you just need to change the widths, and remove any margins or padding.

**p.s.** You really should consider moving away from inline styles and use an external stylesheet with Id's and class names.

Comment: Yes, I'm only using inline styles to test and build it, then moving to an external stylesheet.